# Display a list/library from one site to another site with SharePoint online (o365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I am looking to display a list and libraries that are on a site from within the same site collection.

In SharePoint On-Prem i could use something like [Sharing Lists and Libraries across SharePoint Sites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4)

However, This does not work for online as I cannot display the page the same same.

I did find another post that looks like it should work for me but the "Data View" button is grayed out in SPD.

[Displaying SharePoint Online lists to parent or sub-sites](http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites)

Anyone have any method to do this? I would like it to be the actual list/library so we can add content from either site to that list/library. So content query/search web parts do not display the data in a way that I like.

Thanks!

Comment: how about content query webpart?

Comment: Hi @DenisMolodtsov, as i mentioned above, this method is not good for what i am looking for. I would like it to look as close to the list look as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Page Viewer web part will best option for you. You need to create a Web part page and insert a Page Viewer Web part under the Media and Content group. Finally set the link of the desired list to the Page viewer web part.

[image: Page view web part]

Refer [Page Viewer Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-a-web-page-folder-or-file-on-a-classic-sharepoint-page-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527)

Answer (score 0):

Do you place the cursor between the "

Does it works if you open AllItems.apsx for another list?

Try to go to ‘Edit Tab’ and click on ‘Parse HTML’, it would enable the ‘Data views’ tab again.
 [image]

Run the SharePoint Designer 2013 as Administrator see if it helps.

More troubleshooting steps to resolve Data View is disabled in SharePoint Designer 2013:

https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/19/dataview-is-disabled-sharepoint-designer-2013/

Another method, you can display list/library view using iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/<list/library>/AllItems.aspx" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></iframe>
```